# Diastereoselective epoxidation of acyclic alkenes with VO(acac)2

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, stereochemistry, transition-metals

I've been reading about diastereoselective epoxidation of acyclic alkenes with VO(acac)2. This is taken from Carey, Sundberg Advanced Organic Chemistry Part B:
[image]
The OH and epoxide are syn.
Then, while reading Smith's Organic Synthesis I've found this (the ratio of products is 5.6:1 in favor of the anti):
[image]
which is in contrary with the results from Carey, Sundberg. In an [Evans lecture](http://isites.harvard.edu/fs/docs/icb.topic93502.files/Lectures_and_Handouts/08-Olefin_Addn-1.pdf) the syn stereoselectivity is explained while in [this lecture](http://www.massey.ac.nz/~gjrowlan/oxid/epox.pdf) the anti selectivity is explained. Apparently different sources give opposite selectivities. What is the true explanation here? Is the syn or anti selectivity predominant?

Comment: Have you looked at the classic Evans, Fu paper on directed reactions? I want to say it's in JOC.

Comment: Seems like Carey and Sundberg were wrong.